# How to use light table in python script?

Tags: python, lighttable

I am just newbie in python. I have installed it as per directions and for tool I am using  LightTable but when I try to compile the program it shows error

```
python: can't open file '"C:\Users\vish\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$EX00.867\LightTable\plugins\python\py-src\ltmain.py"': [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I don't know what it is, I even set the path while installing python.

Comment: Are you sure it's the right version?

Comment: Are you trying open file from RAR file ?

Comment: What program do you try to compile ? Script in Python doesn't have to be compiled.

Comment: I am using python 3 , i just wrote a simple program in on light table then then to see the result in console i hit cltr+enter then it shows above mentioned error.

Comment: Did you check the encoding?  e.g. on the second line:
#!/usr/bin/python\n
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-